# MySql, показать права сразу нескольких пользователей

Tags: mysql

Команда SHOW GRANTS выводит права одного пользователя, можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы выводились права сразу нескольких?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23265/mysql-show-grants-for-all-users

Answer (score 0):

Можно так

```
 select * from information_schema.user_privileges;
```